# tarfile filter in python 3.7

Tags: python, python-3.7, tarfile

This is the part of my backup script that I separated for testing. This used to work in python 3.6 but I am getting errors in python 3.7. I checked the docs but can't really figure out what changed.

```
#! /usr/bin/python

import os
import tarfile
import arrow


stmp = arrow.now().format('YYYY-MM-DD')
backup_path = "/home/akya/playground/"

###########################################################
# Functions
###########################################################

def exclude_function(filename):
    if filename in exclude_files or os.path.splitext(filename)[1] in exclude_files:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def compress():
    with tarfile.open(myfile, "w:gz") as tar:
        for name in L:
            tar.add(name, filter=exclude_function)

path1 = "/home/akya/playground/test"
backup_name = "test-"

L = [path1]
exclude_files = [".sh", ".html", ".json", "/home/akya/playground/test/.git"]
myfile = str(backup_path + backup_name + stmp + ".tar.gz")

compress()
```

I want the tarfile to exclude any extensions and paths in exclude_files.  and this is what I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "exec.py", line 33, in <module>
    compress()
  File "exec.py", line 24, in compress
    tar.add(name, filter=exclude_function)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/tarfile.py", line 1934, in add
    tarinfo = filter(tarinfo)
  File "exec.py", line 16, in exclude_function
    if filename in exclude_files or os.path.splitext(filename)[1] in exclude_files:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/posixpath.py", line 122, in splitext
    p = os.fspath(p)
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not TarInfo
```

Can anyone point out the change required? or a better way to use filters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `filter` callback passes a [`TarInfo`](https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/tarinfo-objects.html) structure to your callback, so you can filter by something else than name: date, size, modification time (looks very much like a `stat` object)...

Also, it doesn't work that way (returning booleans), you have to return `None` if you want to exclude this entry:

> TarFile.add(name, arcname=None, recursive=True, *, filter=None)
>
> ...
>   If filter is given, it should be a function that takes a TarInfo object argument and **returns the changed TarInfo object. If it instead returns None the TarInfo object will be excluded from the archive**. See Examples for an example.

In your case, just pick the `.name` field and return `None` if if matches your filter. Else return the same `tarinfo` structure you received.

```
def exclude_function(tarinfo):
    filename = tarinfo.name
    return None if filename in exclude_files or os.path.splitext(filename)[1] in exclude_files else tarinfo
```

(note that I don't know why it worked for you in earlier versions, maybe you added that `or os.path.splitext(filename)[1] in exclude_files` part which reveals that the type is incorrect - the first `in` test wouldn't crash even with an object of the wrong type - but that's the proper way of doing it)

Comment: Thanks, I understand it better now.